# Hover effect on google font icon disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hover effect on *google font icon* disappearing when trying to reach a link embedded in it. I implemented a similar concept but on image and it works perfectly. Pretty sure I am going wrong somewhwere in CSS

```js
$('#LanguageQ').hover(function(){
$('.customtooltip').show();
}, function(){
$('.customtooltip').hide(); 
});
```

```css
.customtooltip{
    background-color: #666666 !important;
    color: #E7E7E7;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
    left:12%;
    width: 36%;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.mandatory {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
}
.mandatory {
    position: relative;
}
.mandatory:active::before {
    content: '';
}
.mandatory::before {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 4%;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.Input-icon {

    position: absolute;

    top: 26%;

    right: 6%;

    z-index: 5;

    font-size: 3ch;

    color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div>

  <div class="customtooltip">Can't find your language? Please <a href="">contact us</a></div>
  <div class="mandatory">
  <div class="Input-icon material-icons"
                                           id="LanguageQ">help_outline</div>
    <input type="text" name="language[]" id="name_input"  class=" nameinput form-control inputfield input gray mandatory" 
                                       list="huge_list" placeholder="Languages">
</div>
```

**Expected:**
I need to be able to go to the link when the hover text appears.

**What I have tried so far:**
Created a hidden div to increase the area of the hover able area (can add the code if required)

Any help or pointers will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place the `.customtooltip` div after `#LanguageQ` div. This is necessary for the css code `#LanguageQ:hover + .customtooltip {display: block;}` to work.
2. Make the `.customtooltip` class's `width: 100%;`. Or change it's `width/position` as necessary.
3. Delete the jQuery code. I'm giving you a css only solution.
4. Add the following css:

   `#LanguageQ:hover + .customtooltip {
       display: block;
   }
   .customtooltip:hover {
       display: block;
   }`

```css
.customtooltip{
    background-color: #666666 !important;
    color: #E7E7E7;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
    left:12%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.mandatory {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
}
.mandatory {
    position: relative;
}
.mandatory:active::before {
    content: '';
}
.mandatory::before {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 4%;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.Input-icon {

    position: absolute;

    top: 26%;

    right: 6%;

    z-index: 5;

    font-size: 3ch;

    color: #cecece;
}

#LanguageQ:hover + .customtooltip {
    display: block;
}
.customtooltip:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div>

  
  <div class="mandatory">
  <div class="Input-icon material-icons"
                                           id="LanguageQ">help_outline</div>
    <div class="customtooltip">Can't find your language? Please <a href="">contact us</a></div>
    <input type="text" name="language[]" id="name_input"  class=" nameinput form-control inputfield input gray mandatory" 
                                       list="huge_list" placeholder="Languages">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I am out now. Will try when as soon as I reach home and let you know.

Comment: It works as expected now. I wish I knew about stack overflow earlier. Thank you for your help. Much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through many ways, one way is this:

```js
$('.contain').hover(function() {
  $('.customtooltip').show();
}, function() {
  $('.customtooltip').hide();
});
```

```css
.customtooltip {
  background-color: #666666 !important;
  color: #E7E7E7;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.mandatory {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
}

.mandatory {
  position: relative;
}

.mandatory:active::before {
  content: '';
}

.mandatory::before {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 4%;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.Input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  right: 6%;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 3ch;
  color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <div class="mandatory">
  
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="customtooltip">Can't find your language? Please <a href="">contact us</a></div>
    <div class="Input-icon material-icons" id="LanguageQ">help_outline</div>
  </div>
    
    <input type="text" name="language[]" id="name_input" class=" nameinput form-control inputfield input gray mandatory" list="huge_list" placeholder="Languages">
  </div>
```

Here, I have wrapped your `.customtooltip` and `#languageQ` `div`'s together and applied the `javascript` `hover` function on the container itself. This way I have included both your elements in the `hover` function, which was previously including only the `#languageQ` div only, thus causing it to disappear as soon as you move out of the div.

Another way to work around the issue it to nest your target element (in your case: `.customtooltip`) inside the hovered one (`#languageQ`) without the need to use javascript at all. Just using css alone.

```
#Target:hover, #Hovered:hover + #Target
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I am not at home now. Will try it and get back to you